# Given a $3m\times m$ table, how many ways can it be filled by $x$'s & $o$'s such that each column has at least $2$ $x$'s?

Tags: combinatorics

Looking at this treat I thought it's a pretty easy one. Apparently not :]. Well,

> Given a $ 3m \times m $ table, how many ways can we fill it with $x$'s and $o$'s, such that each column has at least $2$ $x$'s?

Well, my idea was pretty simple:

Let's have a look at all the possible ways to fill this table. We have $ 3m^2 $ cells, and 2 options for each. Then we have $ 2^{3m^2} $ ways to fill the table. Than, lets subtract all cases where $x$ appears once. This case looks this way:
$$ \prod_{i=1}^{m} \binom{3m}{1} = \binom{3m}{1} \cdot \binom{3m}{1} \cdot \binom{3m}{1}\dots\binom{3m}{1}$$
Then, we have $1$ single option to fill the table without x's at all. In conclusion, we have $$2^{3m^2}-(3m)^m - 1$$
BUT, looking at the final answers in the homework solutions, it says:
$$ (2^{3m} - 3m - 1)^m $$
Seriously, I don't understand how they got that. Does my way makes sense, or do I miss something here?

Comment: Your product is for the case where every $x$ appears once in *every* column (not just one column).  You are also ignoring the case where $x$ does not appear at all.  Hint: How many ways are there, in a single column, for there to be at least $2$ $x$'s?

Comment: By the way, you didn't specify if there were 3n rows or columns and n columns or rows.  Also if you do subtraction, watch out for double counting.  In fact.... don't do subtraction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the solution (and working backwards) we understand that the solution considers each column separately:

1. $2^{3m}$ ways to fill it (without restrictions).
2. $3m$ ways with one $x$,
3. $1$ way with no $x$

So, there are $(2^{3m}-3m-1)$ ways to fill one column with the given restriction. Since there are $m$ columns which you can fill independently, there are: $$(2^{3m}-3m-1)^m$$ ways to complete the task.

---

The mistake in your reasoning is that you consider all columns at once. You count the ways that *all columns simultaneously* have $1$ $x$ or $0$ $x$'s but this ignores cases where for example the first column has no $x$'s and the rest $1$ $x$. You considered the whole table at once, but since the restriction concerns columns and columns can be filled independently, you should have followed the same approach by column-wise (as in the solution).

Comment: Awesome. Thanks a lot!

Comment: In your correcting the reasoning you are implying all columns have at most one x.  Only one column need have at most one x.  Subtraction probably isn't the best way as account for double, triple etc. Counting will be a bear.  Can be done though.

Comment: @fleablood No, I do no imply this. I count the ways to fill a column correctly and then raise to the number of columns. So, each column has at least 2.

Comment: "but this ignores cases where for example the first column has no x's and the rest 1 x"  It also ignores the case where the first column has no x's and the rest have 1 *or more*  x.

Comment: I'm not talking about you solution, which is perfect, I'm talking about your explanation as to why the OP made a mistake.  Which is also correct, but doesn't go far enough.

Comment: @fleablood Ok, now I see it. Thanks for elaborating, your observation is indeed correct. I will correct it as soon as not from mobile.